# How to close browser tab in Ranorex?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser, ranorex

Was trying to close browser tab in Ranorex. The shortcut key "Ctrl+W" seems to work with Chrome and Firefox, but IE closes the application and not a tab.
Please help.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why can't you simply click the cross on the tab?

Comment: Also, I just checked and on IE11, and Ctrl+W works for closing the current tab. Do you mean the Ranorex application closes, or the whole browser?

Comment: Please post the IE version

Comment: It did work with Ctrl+W. The issue was it was applying the action even before it opened the new window. Had to add a delay of 3 secs.

Comment: The delay sounds a bit bad. Try to use the Exists method or validate a certain object in the new window before closing the tab. You will not have any issues with delays then.

Answer (score 2):

3 simple steps:

- Use the spy to **uniquely** identify the tab you want to close.
- Add the item to your repository.
- Drag the item from the repository in a recording and when prompted for an action to perform, select "Close Application".

I have successfully tested this on IE 11 with Ranorex 5.4.6.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Close Application closes my 2nd in-focus tab of Firefox, closes my first tab that I actually only wanted and closes browser all together.  :-(

Comment: The tab you want to close must be uniquely identified using the spy.  I have highlighted the word "uniquely" since it is really important for the Close Application action to properly close the desired tab.