# How to call a running Ranorex test in a loop?

Tags: c#, testing, ranorex, testautomationfx

I have recorded & partly written a test for a Website, which works for a specific browser type. The user can modify a class field of the so-called `EBrowserType` type, which is an `enum` I have created. It contains all browser types that Ranorex can handle.

Now, I was asked to make a loop over the whole test, where all the browser types are called. I run into problems, as the existing test is a group of recordings, where the user clicked at some point into a text field of the opened browser of the requested browser type. This seems to be no more possible in a loop, as the code itself creates the browser & closes it after that.

In the original code, there is a SETUP part that openes the browser, and a recording that follows.
[image]
This recording is called `SearchJobRegionRecording` & starts with a mouse click into the search field of the browser. In the automatically created C# file, this looks as follows:

```
[TestModule("c7957eb6-feec-4dce-aef3-6af20fa71b8b", ModuleType.Recording, 1)]
public partial class SearchJobRegionRecording : ITestModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds an instance of the IVMJobsiteTest.IVMWebsiteTestRepository repository.
    /// </summary>
    public static IVMJobsiteTest.IVMWebsiteTestRepository repo = IVMJobsiteTest.IVMWebsiteTestRepository.Instance;
    […]

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("Ranorex", "8.0")]
    void ITestModule.Run()
    {
        Mouse.DefaultMoveTime = 0;
        Keyboard.DefaultKeyPressTime = 0;
        Delay.SpeedFactor = 100.00;

        Init();

        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Mouse", "Mouse Left Click item 'Home.Text' at 128;8.", repo.Home.TextInfo, new RecordItemIndex(0));
        repo.Home.Text.Click("128;8");
        […]
    }
}
```

As you can see, a `repo` object is required to access the browser instance.
[image]
[image]
**My question:** How can I get the browser instance in my browser-looping code? The only hint about the created browser seems to be the process ID.

Here is the respective part for the browser-looping code:

```
public void TestAllBrowsers()
{
    foreach (EBrowserType browser in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EBrowserType)))
    {
        foreach (Point size in sizes)
        {
            Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Code", "Open with the " + browser + " browser of "
                       + size.X + '×' + size.Y + " size " + url);
                BaseCodeCollection.KillCurrentBrowser(browser);
                var height = (short) size.X;
                var width = (short) size.Y;

                int processID = BaseCodeCollection.OpenBrowser(height, width, url, browser, isVerbose);

                DetermineOriginalVacancies();

                EnterSearchWords(); // HERE, A RepoItemInfo or something like that should be passed so that a mouse click is possible.

                AnalyzeSearchResultsMethod();

                CloseBrowser();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the following answer which explains how to close any browser instance using only repo item? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142841/how-to-close-browser-tab-in-ranorex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question but will try to give you as much hint as I can. I have successfully created a small test suite that basically does the following, without using any user code:

- Iterate the list of supported browsers (IE, Chrome, etc):

  - Open Bing in a browser (**StartBrowser**)
  - Click search field (repo item) (ClickSearchTerm)
  - Iterate through search terms:

    - Enter text in search field (repo item) (SetSearchTerm)
    - Clear text in search field (repo item) (ClearSearchTerm)
  - Close browser instance (repo item) (**CloseBrowser**)

All those steps are contained in a test case which iterates through the list of supported browser (IE and Chrome in my example but it would work with any browser that is supported by Ranorex).

My repo items:

Bing web document: `/dom[@caption='Bing' and @page='']` (ensure spy is finding only one instance of web document or else CloseBrowser will fail)

Bing search field (under Bing repository item): `.//input[#'sb_form_q']`

The **StartBrowser** recording is simply an Open Browser action (with Url and Browser as arguments) followed with a 2s delay (to load page).
The **CloseBrowser** recording is simply a Close application action with the Bing web document repo item as argument.

Note that my example *does not need the browser instance anywhere*, that is why I do not exactly know if this answers your question.  The only recording that requires a browser parameter is the *StartBrowser* recording.  All other recordings are using repository items which are browser agnostic (which is one of the strength of using Ranorex).

If my example does not help you with your issue, feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is possible by using `$variables` that are read from CSV files.

Comment: I am happy to have helped. Regarding the second sentence, I do not understand what you are talking about.  If you wonder how to iterate browser types, as a first step, I would use a "Simple data table" in the test suite and bind it to the StartBrowser recording.